# Modulo operator in Python

Tags: python, operators, modulo

What does modulo in the following piece of code do?

```
from math import *
3.14 % 2 * pi
```

How do we calculate modulo on a floating point number?

Answer (score 67):

When you have the expression:

```
a % b = c
```

It really means there exists an integer `n` that makes `c` as small as possible, but non-negative.

```
a - n*b = c
```

By hand, you can just subtract `2` (or add `2` if your number is negative) over and over until the end result is the smallest positive number possible:

```
  3.14 % 2
= 3.14 - 1 * 2
= 1.14
```

Also, `3.14 % 2 * pi` is interpreted as `(3.14 % 2) * pi`. I'm not sure if you meant to write `3.14 % (2 * pi)` (in either case, the algorithm is the same. Just subtract/add until the number is as small as possible).

Comment: I prefer the explanation x%y is x - (math.floor(x/y)*y) which is the same as what you said but looks more understandable to me

Comment: @sabbahillel And that is why `(-123) % 10 == 7` in python3, while the result is -3 in other languages like C++. Because `(-123) - (math.floor(-123/10)*10) == 7`

Comment: @veryhit Do you know any reference to the Python sourceCode where % is defined as x - (math.floor(x/y)*y) ? Is % defined differently in cPython ? I know documentation for the math.fmod method, but I want to know how the native % operator is defined.

Comment: @MNCODE: Here's how it's defined in CPython: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/0301c9bdd1ebd788d1334cf3fe06c48f35bab0dc/Objects/floatobject.c#L587-L615

Answer (score 26):

In addition to the other answers, the [`fmod` documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/math.html#math.fmod) has some interesting things to say on the subject:

> `math.fmod(x, y)`
>
> Return `fmod(x, y)`, as defined by the platform C
>   library. Note that the Python expression `x % y` may not return the same
>   result. The intent of the C standard is that `fmod(x, y)` be exactly
>   (mathematically; to infinite precision) equal to `x - n*y` for some
>   integer n such that the result has the same sign as `x` and magnitude
>   less than `abs(y)`. Python’s `x % y` returns a result with the sign of `y`
>   instead, and may not be exactly computable for float arguments. For
>   example, `fmod(-1e-100, 1e100)` is `-1e-100`, but the result of Python’s
>   `-1e-100 % 1e100` is `1e100-1e-100`, which cannot be represented exactly as a float, and rounds to the surprising `1e100`. For this reason,
>   function `fmod()` is generally preferred when working with floats, while
>   Python’s `x % y` is preferred when working with integers.

Answer (score 3):

Same thing you'd expect from normal modulo .. e.g. `7 % 4 = 3`, `7.3 % 4.0 = 3.3`

Beware of floating point accuracy issues.

Answer (score 2):

same as a normal modulo  `3.14 % 6.28 = 3.14`, just like `3.14%4 =3.14` `3.14%2 = 1.14` (the remainder...)

Comment: @MadPhysicist what? the order of operations of modulo is the same as pow ... certainly less than equals ... so whats the issue?

Comment: `%` has the same precedence as `/`, which is definitely less than pow (same as times though). `3.14 % 2 * pi` is the same as `(3.14 % 2) * pi == 1.14 * pi` rather than `3.14 % (2 * pi)`.

Comment: I dont have any times or divides in my answer... if I did I would probably group things with parens ... Im not entirely sure what you are saying Oh I c now ... in the original question its not quite clear where the OP would like the parens `3.14 % ( 2*pi)` however is still `3.14` which my example was trying to demonstrate with a number less than 3.14 ... afaik the question was not about the order of operations but meh

Comment: Fair enough. I can't remove the downvote now, although the answer makes sense now that you explained it.

Answer (score 1):

**you should use fmod(a,b)**

`While abs(x%y) < abs(y) is true` mathematically, for `floats` it may not be true numerically due to `roundoff`.

For example, and assuming a platform on which a `Python float` is an `IEEE 754` double-precision number, in order that `-1e-100 % 1e100` have the same sign as `1e100`, the computed result is `-1e-100 + 1e100`, which is numerically exactly equal to `1e100`.

Function `fmod()` in the math module returns a result whose sign matches the sign of the first argument instead, and so returns `-1e-100` in this case. Which approach is more appropriate depends on the application.

`where x = a%b` is used for integer modulo