# How do you find percents of a variable in Python?

Tags: python

I can't figure out how you find a percentage of a variable in Python. This is the example of the code:

```
money =546.97
week=0
for i in range(10):
    money=money+16
    money=money+(5% money)
    print('you have',money,'dollars')
    week=week+4
    print(week)
i = i +1
```

It always just adds 21 because it sees 5% and gives the equation (5% money) the value of 5.

Comment: For example, 8 percent of `x` is just `0.08*x`.

Comment: @ForceBru: `0.08 * x`

Comment: @ForceBru: `0.8` is 80%

Comment: oops, my Python is relatively good, but my math seems to be not as brilliant :D

Comment: the w on the first line isn't supposed to be there

Comment: @WillShepard, if something is not supposed to be there, you always can [edit it out](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38284177/edit).

Comment: @WillShepard I've proposed an edit to clean up the typos a bit, but I left the rest the same.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Forcebru and vaultah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `%` symbol in python is the [modulo operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12754680/modulo-operator-in-python) in python.

It doesn't compute a percent, rather `x % y` determines the remainder after dividing `x` by `y`.

If you want the percentage of a variable, you just have to multiply it by the decimal value of the percent:

```
money * .05
# 5 % of money
```

Answer (score 5):

While the `%` symbol means "percent of" to us, it means *an entirely different thing* to Python.

In Python, `%` is the [*modulo operator*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation). Takes the thing on the left, divides it by the thing on the right, and *returns the remainder of the division*.

```
>>> 9 % 4
1
>>> 9 % 3
0
```

So when you do `5% money`, Python reads it as "divide `5` by `money` and return the remainder". That's not what you want at all!

To answer the question, we need to look at *what* a percentage is. [*Percent*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/percent) comes from Latin *per cent*, meaning "per one hundred things". So "five percent" literally means "take five out of every hundred things." Okay, great! So what?

So to find a percentage of a number, you must *multiply* that number by its decimal percentage value. 5% is the same thing as `0.05`, because `0.05` represents "five one-hundredths" or "five things for every hundred things".

---

Let's rewrite your code a little bit (and I'll clean up the formatting somewhat).

```
money = 546.97
for i in range(10):
    week = i * 4
    money += 16
    money += (0.05 * money)
    print("On week {week} you have {money:.2f} dollars.".format(week=week, money=money))
```

I made a few adjustments:

- Instead of manually incrementing both `i` and `week`, let the loop take care of that; that's what it's for, after all!
- Replaced `(5% money)` with `(0.05 * money)`, which is how Python will understand what you want
- Replaced your print statements with a single statement

  - Used the advanced formatting `{__:.2f}` to produce a number that cuts off to just two decimal places (which is usual for money, but you can erase the `:.2f` if you want the full floating-point value)
  - See [6.1.3 — Format String Syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) for more information about how these arguments work
- Replaced statements like `money = money + x` with `money += x` because it's more concise and easier to read to advanced programmers (in my opinion)
- Adjusted whitespace around operators for readability