# Why do I get these numbers when I have made a range that starts from 7 to 1000000, with 7 as increment number

Tags: python, error-handling, range

```
sevens = range(7, 1000000, 7)

x = int(input("Please enter a positive number less than one million: "))

if x in sevens:
    print("{} is divisible by seven.".format(x))
```

My question is why do I get the following as output? Why 3510 as the starting number when the ranges begins with 7?

```
3510, 83517, 83524, 83531, 83538, 83545, 83552, 83559, 83566, 83573, 83580, 83587, 83594, 83601, 83608, 83615, 83622, 83629, 83636, 83643......
```

Does the error has to do something with the computer memory or is the problem in my IDE(Pycharm Jetbrains)?

Thank you!

Comment: Your code and your Output do not correlate.

Answer (score 1):

To test if a number is fully divisible by another number use the `%` (aka Modulo) operation that gives you the rest of said division:

```
x = int(input("Please enter a positive number less than one million: "))

if x%7 == 0:
    print("{} is divisible by seven.".format(x))
    print("It fits {} times.".format(x//7))
else:
    print("{} is not divisible by seven - theres a rest of {}.".format(x,x%7))
```

Further reading:

- [Modulo operator in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12754680/modulo-operator-in-python)
- [binary-arithmetic-operations](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations) - binary = operating on 2 things, % is inside that.

Answer (score 1):

This is your IDE (Pycharm) problem. Update your IDE. I ran the same code and I have the output starting from 7,14,... and so on.