# How to generate pyramid of numbers (using only 1-3) using Python?

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, design-patterns

I'm wondering how to create a pyramid using only element (1,2,3) regardless of how many rows.

For eg. Rows = 7 ,

```
1
22
333
1111
22222
333333
1111111
```

I've have tried creating a normal pyramid with numbers according to rows.

eg.

```
1
22
333
4444
55555
666666
```

## Code that I tried to make a Normal Pyramid

```
    n = int(input("Enter the number of rows:"))

    for rows in range (1, n+1):  
        for times in range (rows): 
            print(rows, end=" ")

        print("\n")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to adjust your ranges and use the modulo operator `%` - it gives you the remainer of any number diveded by some other number.Modulo 3 returns 0,1 or 2.  Add 1 to get your desired range of values:

```
1 % 3 = 1  
2 % 3 = 2 # 2 "remain" as 2 // 3 = 0 - so remainder is:  2 - (2//3)*3 = 2 - 0 = 2 
3 % 3 = 0 # no remainder, as 3 // 3 = 1 - so remainder is:  3 - (3//3)*3 = 3 - 1*3 = 0
```

Full code:

```
n = int(input("Enter the number of rows: "))
print()
for rows in range (0, n):                 # start at 0
    for times in range (rows+1):          # start at 0
        print( rows % 3 + 1, end=" ")   # print 0 % 3 +1 , 1 % 3 +1, ...,  etc.

    print("")
```

Output:

```
Enter the number of rows: 6
1 
2 2 
3 3 3 
1 1 1 1 
2 2 2 2 2 
3 3 3 3 3 3
```

---

See:

- [Modulo operator in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12754680/modulo-operator-in-python)
- [What is the result of % in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4432208/what-is-the-result-of-in-python)
- [binary-arithmetic-operations](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations)

Answer (score 0):

Using cycle from itertools, i.e. a generator.

```
from itertools import cycle

n = int(input("Enter the number of rows:"))

a = cycle((1,2,3))
for x,y in zip(range(1,n),a):
   print(str(x)*y)
```

*(update)* Rewritten as two-liner

```
from itertools import cycle
n = int(input("Enter the number of rows:"))
print(*[str(y)*x for x,y in zip(range(1,n),cycle((1,2,3)))],sep="\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

A one-liner (just for the record):

```
>>> n = 7
>>> s = "\n".join(["".join([str(1+i%3)]*(1+i)) for i in range(n)])
>>> s
'1\n22\n333\n1111\n22222\n333333\n1111111'
>>> print(s)
1
22
333
1111
22222
333333
1111111
```

Nothing special: you have to use the modulo operator to cycle the values.

`"".join([str(1+i%3)]*(1+i))` builds the (i+1)-th line: i+1 times `1+i%3` (thats is 1 if i=0, 2 if i=1, 3 if i=2, 1 if i=4, ...).

Repeat for i=0..n-1 and join with a end of line char.