# How do I use modular arithmetic on a list, I wish to mod 121 after each enumerated number?

Tags: python, list, math, modular, modulo

I have a list that's is enumerated and I wish to use modular arithmetic on each number, but not the enumerated numbers.  How do I do this?
This question regards only list modular arithmetic not a simple operation.

How do I mod 121 each of these numbers in the list (236, 242, 248) all at once?

```
    lst1 = [22, 236, 23, 242, 24, 248]
    print(mod 121 lst1)
```

Comment: list comprehension or numpy.mod. `[nber % 121 for nber in lst1]` or `np.mod(lst1, 121)`

Comment: How do you compute *one* of the values mod 121? Repeat that.

Comment: You loop over the list and apply the operation to each element.

Comment: Thanks Buckeye14Guy, can you please add a print feature to the code?:)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Modulo operator in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12754680/modulo-operator-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

[List comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html#generator-expressions-and-list-comprehensions) are the typical way to perform an operation on each element in an input iterable, returning a new `list`:

```
print([x % 121 for x in lst1])
```

That's roughly equivalent to:

```
newlst = []
for x in lst1:
    newlst.append(x % 121)
print(newlst)
```

but should run significantly faster, and (for simple cases like this) is easier to read.

**Update:** It seems like you only want to apply this to every other element in the `list`, so just slice it down before performing the comprehension:

```
print([x % 121 for x in lst1[1::2]])
```

`lst1[1::2]` is a slice that makes a new `list` with only the odd-index elements (1, 3, 5, ...), so you only operate on `[236, 242, 248]`.

Comment: Yes but I don't want to mod the enumerated numbers thanks

Comment: @TomE.O'Neil: Huh? You need to describe your problem better then, including desired output, because even rereading your question, I can't figure out what else you might want.

Comment: @TomE.O'Neil: Made a guess at what you meant (the even indices are the "enumerated" numbers, the odds are the "values"). That handle it?

Comment: Hi shadowRanger, you have mod 121 in the list yet I need to maintain and still see the enumerated numbers.  I'm working on number theory at the moment for prime numbers and I have found a formula which finds factors so any help with maintaining the enumerated numbers and only mod 121 the numbers after every enumerated number is helpfule.  thanks

Comment: @TomE.O'Neil: I can't make sense of your requirements at all. Please edit in a few example inputs and desired outputs into your question.

Comment: ShadowRanger you have solved it and I gave you a point thanks can you please have a stab at this question?     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58868162/how-do-i-subtract-11-from-a-list-and-mod-121-the-same-list-all-at-once?noredirect=1#comment104005575_58868162

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished with a lambda and map method:

```
mod_lamda = lambda x: x % 121
lst1 = list(map(mod_lambda, lst1))
```

Or this could be accomplished iteratively

```
for i in range(len(lst1)):
  lst1[i] = lst1[i] % 121
```

Comment: Any use of `list(map(...))` that relies on a `lambda` as the mapping function will lose to an equivalent list comprehension that can inline the operation from the `lambda` (avoiding the function call overhead entirely). `map` only pulls off meaningful wins when it can use an existing function implemented in C (and thereby avoid bytecode execution entirely).

Comment: Good to know. Thanks @ShadowRanger!