# How do I subtract 11 from a list and mod 121 the same list all at once?

Tags: python, list, math, subtraction, modular

This is for prime number theory.  This theory which actually shows up as an axiom factors numbers like 2^n-1 where n=11 or n=23 or n=29.  Of course it would not factor n=7 or n=31 when those are Mersenne prime numbers.

Hopefully I can get help here I wish to do this all at once.  I have this list below. I want to -11 from the entire list and then in the next instance mod 121 the list right after the subtraction while maintaining the enumerated list at the same time.  Can this be done?

I'm getting this error:

```
print([x % 121 for x in lst1])
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Here is part of the list and the code I have:

```
lst1 = [20, '231', 21, '243', 22, '247', 23, '253', 24, '259']
([int(i)-11 if isinstance(i, str) else i for i in lst1])
print([x % 121 for x in lst1])
```

Comment: The second line isn't doing anything because you're throwing away the return. If you reassign it back to `lst1`, does it do what you want?

Comment: What stops you from `(int(i)-11) % 121`?

Comment: lst1 still contains strings, that's why it doesn't work.. do you want to combine the 2nd line with 3rd?

Comment: Thanks a million cs95!!!!!!!:)

Comment: You should convert all the `str` to `int` in your list anyways.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution:

```
lst1 = [20, '231', 21, '243', 22, '247', 23, '253', 24, '259']
print([(int(item)-11)%121 for item in lst1])
```