# Python: is there a way to add 1 to a variable after a separate variable hits a value that's a multiple of five?

Tags: python-3.x, variables, text

I'm making a simple python survival game and I want one day to pass every five turns (so every time x hits a multiple of 5, y = 1 + 1). Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Yes, the key word is "modulo operator".

Comment: sergio tulentsev, could you give me example code using my situation?

Comment: In ruby it'd be `days += 1 if turns % 5 == 0`. I leave it to you to translate this to python. It should turn out largely the same.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Modulo operator in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12754680/modulo-operator-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

```
y=0
for x in range(50):
    if x > 0 and x % 5 == 0:
        y+=1
    print ('x', x)
    print ('y', y)
```

Explanation:

- `for x in range(50)`: Will iterate value of x from 0 to 49
- `if x > 0 and x % 5 == 0`: Checks if x is greater than 0 (you can remove this), and  checks if x modulo 5 is zero
- `y += 1`: Will increment value of y by 1

Comment: `for x in range(50)` does not _print_ anything. `if x > 0` is unnecessary, just start `range` at 1.

Comment: I am printing x in the second last line. x > 0 is totally optional, depending on user's requirement.

Comment: 1. Right. Your explanation says "for x in range(50): --> Will print value of x from 0 to 49". `for ...` _iterates_ over those values, it doesn't print anything. 2. Having an `if` in every iteration to filter out something that could be done by just changing the range of iterations instead is not efficient code.